# graph theory input dictionary output cycle if exists

Tags: python-3.x, graph-theory

What I have wrote below is a function to detect if the graph(shown with the form of dictionary) with a given start point(which is also the end point) could form a circle.
For example,graph={1:[2,3,4],2:[1,5,6],3:[1,7,8],4:[1,9],5:[2],6:[2],7:[3],8:[3,9],9:[4,8]}.If the start point is 3,we could find a circle:3-1-4-9-8-3,however,if the start point is 7,no circle will be found.
My code now only gives True if a circle exists and [] an empty list if it doesn't. What if I want to return a circle(no need to be the longest or shortest one, just any one which fulfills the requirement)?
I'm not sure if I could thinking and coding this way since the purpose has changed.

> '''input:a graph and a start point output:a list function:detect if a
>   circle with the given point as both start point and end point
>   exists'''

```
def cycle(graph,start_point):
    queue=[start_point]
    visited=set()
    visited.add(queue[0])
    while queue:
        from_point=queue.pop() #DFS
        for to_point in graph[from_point]:
            if to_point in visited:
                return True
            else:
                queue.append(to_point)
                visited.add(to_point)
            graph[to_point].remove(from_point)
    return []
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what your goal is. In your question you say you want to detect if there is a cycle containing the starting point. But then in your code it seems you want to check if there is a cycle somewhere in the graph, not necessarily containing the starting point. Please clarify what your goal is.